# Track a stick with blob tracking or by color? Using Kinect, opencv and C#

Tags: c#, opencv, kinect

I want to create a laserlike thing, when I hold a stick in my hand in front of my kinect I need the computer to detect that stick so I can program a laserlight (a simple red line) coming out of my stick.

At this moment I can detect my stick but when I chance my hand position it fails, I'm using `blob tracking`.

```
if ((contours.Area > Math.Pow(25, 2)) && (contours.Area < Math.Pow(80, 2)))
{
    MCvBox2D box = contours.GetMinAreaRect();
    openCVImg.Draw(box, new Bgr(System.Drawing.Color.Green), 2);
    ballCount++;
}
```

I'm thinking about painting my stick (or the top of it) in fluo-green to track it like that. But how to get starting or would you stay with the blob tracking or is there a better way? I found some code examples on the internet (I searched long for this) but I'm not able to get it going, I'm very new to this.

I'm using a `Kinect`, `OpenCV` and `C#`.

Comment: I think color (or even better some different MARKER) might be more stable than blob tracking.

Comment: Yes I think so to, but don't really know where to get started... I will have a look again tonight, anybody know some code examples for kinect with opencv en c#?

Comment: Try searching on SO... I remember some similar questipns. Maybe: "marker tracking"

Comment: I'm still stuck at this point. Can anybody give a direction? It's for OpenCV, C# and with a kinect.